# Embedding a YouTube video with autoplay AND full screen capability enabled

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

I have embedded a YouTube video on a page and the client wants the video to autoplay, in addition to the user having the ability to view video in full screen.  It seems that it's either or - when the autoplay is working, the full screen capability at the bottom of the video is not enabled.  When the autoplay code is removed, the full screen capability is active.

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <iframe src="//youtube.com/embed/4liKzXo2lRM?rel=0&autoplay=1";; modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=1" width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
  </iframe>
</p>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". It must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I'm new to Stack Overflow so not sure of the details I am to provide.  The client wants the video to autoplay and have the user be able to make it full screen.  Here is the code:<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4liKzXo2lRM?rel=0&autoplay=1"; modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=1" width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"><span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span></iframe></p>

Comment: Read it and you will see, it will ask you to provide the `language type`, a short example `<embeded-like-a-champion></embeded-like-a-champion>`. To see if there is no something that you might miss, and more.. Really interesting you will see.

Comment: See right there, now I know you use plain html with an iframe, Which provide me already extremely good information. Now the best would be to include it into your question, let me edit it for you, I will show you how to create a snippet

Comment: Thanks for your help Jonathan.  I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I just have found your problem while searching for an answer to the same problem. And thanks to your code I got it worked for me. 
Perhaps try `allow="fullscreen; autoplay"` and separately `allowfullscreen` 
and in order to make it work in Chrome add `muted` as well (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

This has worked for me.

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <iframe src="//youtube.com/embed/4liKzXo2lRM?rel=0&autoplay=1";; modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=1" width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen muted>
    <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
  </iframe>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/4liKzXo2lRM?rel=0&autoplay=1" allow="autoplay; allowfullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The above code worked for me.

Youtube video of it working for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP5G2OaLpB4